# Could not able to trace Visual studio entry point in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

In my project I was not able to trace from where the entry is happening to the project.
When I am looking into call stack it is giving the hirerchy as

`mfc100d.dll!_DllMainCRTStartup(void* hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void *lpreserved)
ntdll.dll!77328968()

[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!77335c11()

ntdll.dll!7733500a()

ntdll.dll!773335e9()`

Then the code is jumping to 
`CWinApp::InitInstance()`.
But how it is going to `!_DllMainCRTStartup` is being a difficult task for me to trace out.
I am trying since yesterday, but I was not able to find it.

Note:
In settings:

`Entry point is blank`

`No Entry: No`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the Microsoft Debug Symbols to resolve the `[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll]` and see the actual stack in two ways:

1. On the call stack right-click an entry, choose `Symbol Settings...` and then press `Load Symbols from Microsoft symbols servers`
2. `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols` will lead you to the same dialog and again press `Load Symbols from Microsoft symbols servers`

This should at least resolve the stack and show the system calls.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did the same I can see now the hirerchy as `mfc100d.dll!_DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved), 
ntdll.dll!_LdrpCallInitRoutine@16()  + 0x14 bytes, 
ntdll.dll!_LdrpRunInitializeRoutines@4()  + 0x385d bytes, 
ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitializeProcess@8()  - 0x126a bytes, 
ntdll.dll!__LdrpInitialize@8()  + 0x2afa bytes, 
ntdll.dll!_LdrInitializeThunk@8()  + 0x10 bytes`

Comment: But still I am struggling to find out from where was it get called from the project

Comment: LdrpInitialize gets called by the main thread of the process that links against your dll to load all the dependent libraries, it is called even before WinMain() so you won't be able to see nothing more and it is correct. I don't see what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually according to my requirement, I should call `InitInstance()` dirctly. But when I am doing so, execution fails. But when I executed the old code `(Before I did editing)`, it shows in the `call stack` that before it reaches `InitInstance()`, it covers many other paths as I mentioned above.

Comment: I still don't fully understand the issue - are you developing a library, a client program that links to the library, or both? `CWinApp::InitInstance()` should be called from `WinMain()` not DllMainCRTStartup.

Answer (score 1):

A stack trace belonging to the main thread and not going back to the `main()` function terribly sounds like something going wrong while constructing a global object (that is, declared at top-level) to me. You may want to investigate that.

I.e. that `DllMainCRTStartup` function is likely invoked directly from your C++ runtime support library.